# Error while building the project with Deck.gl package

Tags: reactjs, next.js, building, deck.gl

Does anybody know how to fix the problem, that occures in the console while i am trying to build the project?

**Error:**

```
export * from './exports-mapbox';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

**MapComponents imports**

```
import MapGL from 'react-map-gl/dist/esm';
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const DeckGL = dynamic(() => import("deck.gl"), {ssr: false})
import {
  GeoJsonLayer,
  PathLayer,
  SolidPolygonLayer,
  PolygonLayer,
  IconLayer
} from '@deck.gl/layers/dist/esm';
```

**index.js**

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const SRMap = dynamic(() => import('../pages/map/Map'), { ssr: false });

export default Map = () => {
  return (
    <SRMap />
  )
}
```

I have tried to add `"type": "module"` to a package.json file. But it doesn't work.